# What are some methods of logging access to an ASP.NET application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, logging

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, and I suppose IIS can handle logging requests, but I'm trying to find a way to log all actions/requests to my app made by authenticated/unauthenticed users in a format that is easy to read.

E.g. IP address tied to login as userx, usery ran a report, userz logged out, etc.

I want to avoid having to decorate every method/page in my system.  Are there frameworks that will take care of the bulk of such requests?

Answer (score 0):

```
 I believe you need IIS Log files:

 Default place: %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles
 Also look into: %SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\LogFiles
 Use "LogParser" to read the log.
```

Please **[click](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/friis/archive/2014/02/06/how-to-analyse-iis-logs-using-logparser-logparser-studio.aspx)** here for "LogParser" details.

Answer (score 0):

ELmah and Log4Net are commonly used libraries for logging. [Elmah](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) is a plug and play modules for [error logging](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-elmah-cs). It also provide multiple ways to view your logs as well. On the other hand [Log4Net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html) is a general purpose logging library.

You can [read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479332.aspx) how to write one for yourself if you didn't found one suitable for your needs.